# Oracle SQL Query Assistance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Given a table:

```
ID NUMBER
OBJECTID NUMBER
CATEGORYID NUMBER
SCORE NUMBER
SCOREDATE DATE
```

Is it possible to efficiently retrieve the last score (based on `SCOREDATE`) in each distinct category for a given object in one query?

Comment: Is your table indexed? Do you have a non-efficient query so far?

Comment: My table is not indexed. It may be a possibility but I'm not sure right now. I'd imagine I can whip something up with subqueries but it wouldn't seem to be more efficient than just retrieving the data with many queries in my application logic.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted? Am I not allowed to ask for suggested query techniques?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
select v.* from (
select category_id, 
       score, 
       scoredate, 
       row_number() over (partition by category_id order by scoredate desc) rn
from MyTable) v
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want falls into the `[greatest-n-per-group]` tag. One way to achieve the result:

```
SELECT
    t.CategoryId
  , t.Score
FROM
    ( SELECT
          CategoryId
        , MAX(ScoreDate) AS LastScoreDate
      FROM
          TableX
      WHERE
          ObjectId = @ObjectId
      GROUP BY 
          CategoryId
    ) AS grp
  JOIN
      TableX AS t
    ON  grp.Category = t.CategoryId
    AND grp.LastScoreDate = t.ScoreDate
WHERE
    t.ObjectId = @ObjectId
```